# How to pass dynamic attribute/parameter to openDialog?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I need to pass the following ID: `59dc921ffedff606449abef5` dynamically to `MatDialog`. For testing proposes I'am using it as hard coded ID.

Unfortunately all my searches and tries failed and I can't get the id dynamically into the function call. I tried also the `@input` feature, but it didn't help.

**`edit-dilog.component.ts`**:

```
export class EditDialogComponent implements OnInit {
dialogResult:string = '';
constructor(public dialog:MatDialog, public loginService:LoginService ){ }
ngOnInit() {}
openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(EditUserComponent, { data: '59dc921ffedff606449abef5' })
    .afterClosed()
    .subscribe(result => this.dialogResult = result);
}
```

}

**`edit-user.component.ts`**:

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {
    public message:any [];
    public resData: {};
    constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserComponent>, 
                  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: number, 
                  public loginService: LoginService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
          this.loginService.getSingleUser(this.data)
          .subscribe(data => {
              this.resData = JSON.stringify(data);
          })
      }
      onCloseConfirm() {
          this.thisDialogRef.close('Confirm');
      }
      onCloseCancel() {
          this.thisDialogRef.close('Cancel');
      }
}
```

The ID is coming from JSON Response in a service **login-service.ts**:

```
getSingleUser(id) {
    return this.http.get(environment.urlSingleUsers + '/' + id, this.options)
    .map(res => {
        console.log('RES: ' + JSON.stringify( res.json() ) );
        return res.json();
    }).catch( ( error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') );
}

extractData(result:Response):DialogUserData[] {
    return result.json().message.map(issue => {
        return {
            ID: issue._id,
            Email: issue.email,
            Name: issue.fullName
        }
    });
}
```

And here is where I do the call of `openDialog()`:

```
<i class="material-icons" (click)="openDialog()">create</i>
```

For more clarification here is how the JSON Response comes:

```
"message": [
  {
    "_id": "59415f148911240fc812d393",
    "email": "jane.doe@foo.de",
    "fullName": "Jane Doe",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2017-06-14T16:06:44.457Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5943b80be8b8b605686a67fb",
    "email": "john.doe@foo.de",
    "fullName": "John Doe",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2017-06-16T10:50:51.180Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar, though I'm a little bit confused by how you name the components (seems should be the other way around). 
 
You can try: fetch the data (user) first and then (actually) open the dialog in your controlling component:

**edit-dialog.component.ts:**

```js
openDialog(id: string) {
  this.loginService.getSingleUser(id)
    .subscribe(user=> {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditUserComponent, {
        data: user
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
      });
    });
}
```

You can then access the dialog data (user) to render the dialog view:

**edit-user.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() { 
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

In this way, you can pass the id dynamically:

```
<i class="material-icons" (click)="openDialog(id)">create</i>
```

where the `id` can be a member of your controlling component.